QR decomposition in R is incorrect?
Consider the following code :
set.seed(1)
n <- 30

X <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
Z <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
A <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
W <- 4*X + 8*Z 
B <- 6*X + 9*Z + 7*A

mat <- cbind(X, Z, W, B, A)

qr_decomp <- qr(mat)
Q <- qr.Q(qr_decomp)
R <- qr.R(qr_decomp)

print(abs(Q %*% R - mat))

The outcome is, rather surprisingly :
                 X            Z            B            W            A
 [1,] 4.440892e-16 0.000000e+00 16.917096254 16.917096254 0.000000e+00
 [2,] 0.000000e+00 2.081668e-16  0.010181098  0.010181098 2.040035e-15
 [3,] 0.000000e+00 5.551115e-17  3.544589924  3.544589924 4.440892e-16
 [4,] 0.000000e+00 1.179612e-16  3.332771675  3.332771675 2.230854e-15
 [5,] 5.551115e-17 2.220446e-16  5.920956475  5.920956475 1.332268e-15
 [6,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00  0.734385235  0.734385235 0.000000e+00
 [7,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 12.054142251 12.054142251 2.220446e-16
 [8,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 11.676220044 11.676220044 2.220446e-16
 [9,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00  3.324361443  3.324361443 2.775558e-17
[10,] 0.000000e+00 1.110223e-16 15.360680667 15.360680667 4.440892e-16
[11,] 0.000000e+00 8.326673e-17  6.187605443  6.187605443 5.551115e-17
[12,] 0.000000e+00 5.551115e-17  4.443300224  4.443300224 1.110223e-16
[13,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00  3.729566689  3.729566689 3.330669e-16
[14,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 10.411419997 10.411419997 1.110223e-16
[15,] 0.000000e+00 1.110223e-16  7.214327660  7.214327660 0.000000e+00
[16,] 6.938894e-18 0.000000e+00  1.242761274  1.242761274 2.775558e-16
[17,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00  2.770841677  2.770841677 0.000000e+00
[18,] 0.000000e+00 1.110223e-16  2.663942807  2.663942807 5.551115e-17
[19,] 0.000000e+00 5.551115e-17  2.050485447  2.050485447 2.775558e-17
[20,] 0.000000e+00 1.110223e-16  2.057736254  2.057736254 1.110223e-16
[21,] 0.000000e+00 5.551115e-17  1.744620506  1.744620506 2.220446e-16
[22,] 0.000000e+00 1.110223e-16  0.005995902  0.005995902 5.551115e-17
[23,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00  8.736858634  8.736858634 0.000000e+00
[24,] 2.220446e-16 2.220446e-16 15.773034091 15.773034091 2.220446e-16
[25,] 0.000000e+00 2.220446e-16  6.830298511  6.830298511 2.220446e-16
[26,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00  4.198795018  4.198795018 1.110223e-16
[27,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00  6.762886371  6.762886371 2.220446e-16
[28,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00  6.114926860  6.114926860 3.885781e-16
[29,] 0.000000e+00 1.110223e-16  2.203551187  2.203551187 1.110223e-16
[30,] 0.000000e+00 2.775558e-17  2.570520052  2.570520052 1.110223e-16

That is, it does not assure mat == Q %*% R, which is incorrect. Why is that? In particular, let it print R will show that the resulting R is 5 by 5, which is incorrect.

Update: if I ask it to print rank, it will correctly print 3. As pointed out in the comments, additional work is required to get a correct QR decomposition in the case where the matrix is not full rank. All I want is a mathematically correct decomposition in QR, with R in the correct size and mat = Q %*% R, with say error < 1e-8 every entry. I appreciate answers that can give the correct QR decomposition in this case. The documentation is impossible to read.

This is explained in the example for the qr.Q() help file. Your matrix is not full rank, so pivoting was used, which means you have to do extra work to recover the original matrix.

That documentation is so hard to read. What exactly do they mean mathematically? Do you mind to elaborate what they are doing and how to obtain a QR decomposition correctly?

The matrix is not full rank, so you need to "undo" the pivot to get the original matrix back. This is demonstrated with an example almost identical to yours in the documentation for qr.Q(). The code below undoes the pivot by changing the column order of R to return the original matrix:
set.seed(1)
n <- 30

X <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
Z <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
A <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
W <- 4*X + 8*Z 
B <- 6*X + 9*Z + 7*A

mat <- cbind(X, Z, W, B, A)

qr_decomp <- qr(mat)
Q <- qr.Q(qr_decomp)
R <- qr.R(qr_decomp)

range(abs(Q %*% R - mat))
#> [1]  0.0000 16.9171

R_ <- R[,order(qr_decomp$pivot)]

range(abs(Q %*% R_ - mat))
#> [1] 0.000000e+00 1.365574e-14

Created on 2024-08-01 with reprex v2.1.1

I guess this is as good as we can get due to numerical difficulties.

@温泽海 I don't know how you could expect any better, the largest difference is at the 13th decimal point.
